# Are there performance issues on sending different number types as parameter to a method?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, jit

Given this function:

```
void function(Double X, Double y, Double Z);
```

Are there performance issues if I send different number data types? For example:

```
function(1, 2, 3); //int, int, int
function(1, 2.2, 1); //int, double, int
function(1.3f, 3.4, 2.34f) //single, double, single
function(1.2f, 1, 1) //single, int, int
```

How does .NET JIT manages this? It does boxing-unboxing? This impacts performance?

Comment: Are we talking about actual literals or variables? If they are literals the C# compiler is doing the implicit conversion and there is no run-time cost. Otherwise there is a small cost for a run-time conversion, but no allocations (boxing/unboxing).

Comment: It's a constant being cast to a type known at compile time. Any undergrad writing a toy compiler would do it all in the compiler. I think the .NET compiler guys just might be able to manage. That is, assuming the code in your example is the code you're asking about.

Comment: A performance cost is only a problem if you are calling this method in a tight loop if the parameter conversion time is significant compared to the total time that the method takes to execute.

Comment: Mmm that's interesting. I'd search a bit to investigate how this works. It's interesting :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exact example will be converted by the compilier, so there's no performance penalty.  If we modify the example a bit:

```
static void Test(double x, double y, double z)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x * y * z);
}

static void Main()
{
    double d1 = 1;
    double d2 = 2;
    double d3 = 3;
    float f1 = 1;
    float f2 = 2;
    float f3 = 3;
    int i1 = 1;
    int i2 = 2;
    int i3 = 3;

    Test(i1, i2, i3);
    Test(i1, d2, i3);
    Test(f1, d2, f3);
    Test(f1, i2, i3);
}
```

Then the story is different.  The compilier will be unlikely to do the conversion for us, so it's necessary for it to emit code to the conversion, for instance, let's take a look at the code for the second call to `Test`

```
IL_004b:  ldloc.s    V_6    // Load the variable i1 onto the stack
IL_004d:  conv.r8           // Convert it to a double
IL_004e:  ldloc.1           // Load the variable d2 onto the stack
IL_004f:  ldloc.s    V_8    // Load the variable i3 onto the stack
IL_0051:  conv.r8           // Convert it to a double
// And call the function:
IL_0052:  call       void Example.ExampleClass::Test(float64,
                                                   float64,
                                                   float64)
```

You can see it has to emit one more instruction each for the two non-doubles.  This isn't a free action, it takes time to compute.

All of that said, I'd be hard pressed to imagine this matters, unless you're calling this function in a very tight loop.

*Edit*

Also, keep an eye out for property accessors.  For instance, these two methods are logically the same if the demo object doesn't change it's length during the `for` loop, but the first one will call `demo.Length` multiple times, which will most certainly be slower than calling it once.

```
var demo = CreateDemo();
for (int i = 0; i < demo.Length; ++i)
{
    // ...
}

// .. vs ..

var demo = CreateDemo();
int len = demo.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The IL explanation was very informative. Yes, I'm trying to do this with a game loop in OpenGL, but I noticed my variables are not always the same type. Some are float, some double, int. That's why I asked. I tested my program in 2 ways in two different computers, one kind of modern (2013) and a very old one (2001). The old one got stressed very fast with thousand of GL lines very quickly when using, as my first solution, templates <T>, then I noticed a lot of performance gain when doing what I asked. I think I will try to do tweaks in just a single data type to see it's performance impact.

Comment: Fair enough, there are indeed cases where it'll matter.  Keep in mind to look out for other potential performance issues, like lots of unnecessary function calls (if you have helper functions that due a trivial activity, for instance, then you're paying a penalty to push values onto the stack then jump to the function when doing the same activity inline will be faster).  Also, things like array access or property accessing are function calls that can be avoided in some cases.

Comment: Ohhh! Property accessing has performance impact O.O?
Actually I'm accesing a lot properties jajaja Maybe this could be something...

Comment: Yep, they're basically a function call (take a look at the ildasm to see how they're implemented, they use the same logic as a function call).  What's more, take a look at my edit, there are some patterns people often fall into without realizing they're doing many such calls in a row when they don't necessarily need to.

Comment: This actually makes me see that sometimes, cool small readable code isn't the best to choose. Using temporary variables, making non anonymous calls every time, and that kind of stuff makes me see sometimes old school code is the best practice :) jajajaja